# Node.js Application with MongoDB on Kubernetes Using Helm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

How can we authenticate to a mongodb database which is in azureVM ?

How can i write helm chart for that ?

What are the prerequisites for that ?

Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Could you provide the main purpose over here? Are you gonna create a nodejs application which is client, working in the AKS cluster, and need a connection to the Mongodb server on different Azure VM?

Comment: Hey hi
My purpose is, already we have nodejs application with mongodb database, but the database is in AzureVM. so i need to create a helm chart for this scenario. i have only path and port value with me. so can you pls guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way how to do that and guide you should be a Microsoft tutorial about Node.js application development for Azure Kubernetes Service using Azure Dev Spaces:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/dev-spaces/get-started-nodejs

There you will get:
1. How to enable Azure Dev Spaces on your AKS
2. How to develop the first Node.js app with sample code
3. How to generate helm chart for Node.js app
4. How to deploy and test it locally

Inside Node.js app you should use the most popular mongodb client which is:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Regarding npm package documentation, there is also a lot of online tutorials on how to work with that package:
https://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html